# Why I cannot import a python script from outside a scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy, python-import

I know this question has been asked a lot of times with some solutions provided (workarounds more than solutions) but I cannot understand why I could not import a python script from outside a scrapy project. I mean that with any other python script, I am able to do it by providing the good import but within a scrapy project no, every script that I import has to be located inside the scrapy project.

Can anyone explain to me why ?

Comment: How are you running the spiders? Locally? With scrapyd? In the cloud? My assumption here is that you actually run the spider in a different environment than all your other python scripts.

Comment: @kutschkem I run it with scrapy crawl myspider

Answer (score 0):

When you run your crawler it gets "basedir" as "scrapy.cfg"s location. If you want to get any script outside of the Scrapy you need to append your path with `sys.path.append`.

For example, when I want to use Django with Scrapy:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('.')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```

If this answer is not enough for you please share your path and more information like library or scripts or your trials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Murat Demir, do you know if its possible to get another directory (upper in the tree) to be the "basedir"  ? It would solve my question, no ?